# FileProvider Not Returning getExternalStorageDir()

Tags: android

I have read post after post on using the fileprovider for providing a uri for camera intent but still cannot get the fileprovider to return the root of the external storage directory.

Here's my provider from the manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.bkbeesites.hivelog.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Here's my provider paths xml

```
<paths>
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Here's my camera intent

```
 private void startCameraIntent(){
    imageCount++;
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String date = df.format(today);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = null;
    try
    {
        // place where to store camera taken picture
        photo = this.createTemporaryFile(hiveId + ""+ StringManipulation.firebaseFormat(date)+imageCount, ".jpg");
        Log.d(TAG,"Photo Tostring: " + photo.toString());
        photo.delete();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Can't create file to take picture!");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please check Device Storage! Image Shot Is Impossible!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"External Files Dir : "+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
            "com.bkbeesites.hivelog.fileprovider",
            photo);

    Log.d(TAG,"imageUri from Camera Intent: " + imageUri.getPath().toString());
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    //start camera intent
    startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And here's my onActivityResult

```
 case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                try
                {
                    /*imgURLs.add(imageUri.getPath());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Image URI from OnActivityResult: " + imageUri.toString());
                    setupGridView();*/

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to load", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

When I create the temporary file it works, it returns /storage/emulated/0/HiveLog/pic.jpg

When I use the getUriForFile it returns /external_files/HiveLog/pic.jpg and therefore either gets a FileNotFoundException or a Failed To Find Configured Root... Obviously there is no external_files directory but I can't figure out how to get fileprovider to return the root external storage directory. I had this working fine with older devices using Uri.fromFile but then got a security error when testing on a newer device. All I want to do is save this image into the HiveLog folder and be able to access it for upload/processing.

Thanks a million for any help offered.

Comment: "When I use the getUriForFile it returns /external_files/HiveLog/pic.jpg" -- you are looking at the path of a `content` `Uri`, which is pointless. Stop using `getPath()`. If you want the `File`, **you already have it**. It is called `photo`.

Comment: Yes but if I just get the Bitmap data from the camera intent and save it to photo it saves a thumbnail. So, following Android Developers I figured I had to use a FileProvider.

Comment: Put the `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and include `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent` (which you have commented out). When you get control again, use the `File` that you used to create the `Uri`. Here is [a complete sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android) demonstrating the use of `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Man this is probably a really stupid question, but before I started with the fileprovider I had been just using the URI in onactivityresult to add to an ArrayList for viewing and then for uploading to firebase storage, now I just can't access the image from the uri. You said to use the file "photo" that I used to create the uri... how do I do that? I know how to create a FileOutputStream, but that doesn't seem like the correct method since the Bitmap I have access to is only a thumbnail.

Comment: Ahh, nevermind! I made it a global variable and just used it in the onactivityresult and it worked! I was backwards in my thinking, because I had been using the URI I thought that was the way to go, but the uriforfile function created the image file and using "photo" was successful! CommonsWare you are a genius and my hero.